# Slide in DIV from the right in CSS? CoolBlue example

Tags: html, css, slide

Ok, is this possible in CSS only?
Check https://www.coolblue.nl/televisies and click the word: 'Advies' in the light blue menu.
You'll see a new page on the right side appear with extra information without you actually leaving the productpage. This is exactly what I need, but it has to be pure CSS.

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Please include a [mre], or at least your own attempt!

Comment: it would be possible, using the checkbox hack you can simulate onclick event and show another div, which can be absolute positioned (or fix)

Comment: It works like a sidebar, which is -100% by default.

Comment: Hope this helpful to you. https://davidwalsh.name/css-slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it depends on what do you want to achieve.

A simple way would be to use the checkbox hack to simply create a hidden checkbox, and a lable for it, whick contains the block to display when the button is clicked. It could be something like this:

```css
#controllbox {
    display: none;
}

.infopage{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: none;
}

#controllbox:checked + label > .infopage {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="controllbox"/>
<label class="linkbutton" for="controllbox">
  Click me!
  <div class="infopage">
    here the text in the info box .....
  </div>
</label>
```

If you want the div to slide in, just change `width` oder `right` property and let it animate with css.

If you need more complex logic, javascript could be a better solution.

**EDIT:**

A JS Solution could looks like this:

```css
.item{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.infobox{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  right: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition: right 0.6s;
}

.infobox.open{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <span class="item" onclick="document.querySelector('#' + this.getAttribute('data-infobox')).classList.toggle('open');" data-infobox="infobox1">Click Me!</span>
</div>
<div id="infobox1" class="infobox">
some text to show
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll try and work this in. The CMS we use doesn't allow for additional jQuery, but it will accept CSS.

Comment: ok, i hope this approach will work for you. Maybe some inline js will work too? A lot of things can be done with css but in many cases some js makes it easier and more comfortable to use

Comment: I can try. Is that an easy update for you on the snippet? I know how to read it, but I just can't write it.

Comment: I added a minimal JS solution, it is very simple and could be improved but it is a working example to get started if you want to try it

Comment: You are an absolute legend! It looks like the CMS accepted this!!! Thank you for your help and keeping it simple!

Comment: I´m glad, i could help you